# EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK - WindowsException was thrown running a test: Error 0x00000000 - whilst running a widget test

Tags: flutter, widget-test-flutter

This is the error message:

```
The following WindowsException was thrown running a test:
Error 0x00000000: The operation completed successfully.
```

I am trying to pumpWidget using a ChangeNotifierProvider.

```
await tester.pumpWidget(
      ChangeNotifierProvider<PageViewModel>(
        create: (_) => PageViewModel(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Page(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Reason I am doing the above is because in my Page() I return a Consumer

```
 return Consumer<PageViewModel>(
      builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold()
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

I have split my problem into parts to understand what was I missing until I bumpped into this and I honestly cannot get out of it.
e.g
Returning just the MaterialApp and calling my page. I read the error message and I have fixed it with the guide flutter was giving.

Comment: hi, did you resolved it? I am facing with same error. if it is resolved please share the solution